# Rustpkg fails to build a package

Tags: rust

I tried to build the example package from [here](https://github.com/steveklabnik/hello) but sadly I get following error:

> error: Couldn't find package std in any of the workspaces in the RUST_PATH (C:\U
>   sers\User\Desktop\test\hello.rust:C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\hello:C:\Users\Use
>   r.rust)

Now it's kinda obvious that there is some issue with RUST_PATH but I am somewhat unable to find documentation concerning it.

note: I'm using Windows 8 64 bit and Rust 0.8

Comment: If at all possible, use master instead of 0.8, which is rather significantly out of date.

Comment: `ruspkg` works terrible on windows, e.g. I doubt that it's anyhow usable on windows for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rustpkg has been removed from basic library and moved into `librustpkg`.

There are alternatives like [Makefile](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) or [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), but I assume the preferred version it's using [cargo-lite](https://github.com/cmr/cargo-lite).

My advice is just look at Rust-CI for a project that uses package manager you like most and copy it's build shamelessly.

UPDATE: A new package manager for rust has been announced. It's called `Cargo`. We'll see how it works out, but that is possible future default.

Answer (score 1):

Rustpkg [has been removed from Rust](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2014-January/008224.html). Hopefully we will get something to replace it.